# Dúvida a respeito de excluir elementos específicos da função clone()

Tags: html, jquery, clone

Me surgiu uma dúvida a respeito da exclusão de elementos específicos quando eu uso a função `clone()`. Gostaria de saber se consigo excluir os elementos `<b>` quando eu chamar a função. Ou seja, o que está escrito "Item", "ID", "Selecione um produto" etc; só apareça na primeira `DIV`, as demais que serão adicionadas, só venham com os valores dos inputs / select.

Isso facilitaria também quando eu fosse imprimir a página, visando que, eu não conseguiria dar um `display:none` nesses elementos através do media queries. Alguém consegue me informar se é possível fazer isto?

index.php:

```
<div id="allProducts">
                    <div class="produtos-wrap" name="produtos-wrap"> <!---- DIV A SER CLONADA / ADICIONADA !---->
                        <div class=" text-center select_height">
                            <b>Item:</b>
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" class="index font-pop input-div" id="index_produto"
                                   name="index_produto[]" value="1" readonly="true">
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center select_height">
                            <b>ID:</b>
                            <br>
                            <input class="font-pop number_id_produto input-div" value="0" readonly="true"
                                   name="id_produto[]">
                        </div>

                        <div class="select-produto select_height">
                            <b>Selecione um produto:</b>
                            <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-show-subtext="false"
                                    data-live-search="true" name="select_produtos[]" id="select_produtos" onchange="initProdutos(this)">
                                <?php
                                foreach ($result2 as $item_produtos) {
                                    echo '<option data-subtext="' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '" value="'
                                        . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '">' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center select_height">
                            <b>Embalagem:</b>
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="edit-input font-pop" name="embalagem[]" value="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center select_height">
                            <b>Preço:</b>
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="preco[]" class="edit-input font-pop" value="0">
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center select_height">
                            <b>Quantidade:</b>
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="edit-input font-pop" value="0"
                                   name="quantidade-produto[]">
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center select_height text-right">
                            <b>Preço do Produto:</b>
                            <br>
                            <input class="font-pop preco-produto input-div" readonly="true" name="preco-produto[]"
                                   value="0">
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center select_height" id="div-remove">
                            <button type="button" class="remover glyphicon glyphicon-remove button-produto"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" id="add-button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign button-produto"></button>
            </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var clone = $('#allProducts').html();
    $(document).on('click', '#add-button', addProd);

    $(document).on('click', '.remover', function () {
        $(this).parents('.produtos-wrap').remove();
        ids();
        calculos();
    });

    function addProd() {
        $('#allProducts').append(clone);
        ids();
    }

    function ids() {
        $("[name='index_produto[]']").each(function (i, e) {
            $(e).val(i + 1);
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Tente trocando esta linha: `var clone = $('#allProducts').html();`, por esta: `var clone = $('#allProducts').html().replace(/<b>.*?<\/b>|<br>/g, "");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quer remover todos os `<b>` e os `<br>`, você pode fazer de duas formas:

### Usando `.remove()`

Converta a variável `clone`, que é uma string com o HTML da div, em objeto HTML com `$.parseHTML()` e em seguida busque as tags `<b>` e `<br>` e remova-os:

```
var clone = $.parseHTML($('#allProducts').html());
$("b, br", clone).remove();
```

### Usando `.replace()`

Usando uma expressão regular (regex) para buscar as tags `<b>` e `<br>`:

```
var clone = $('#allProducts').html().replace(/<b>.*?<\/b>|<br>/g, "");
```

Comment: A opção do .replace() funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado Sam !

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra possibilidade que complementa a resposta do @Sam e que não cabe em um comentário.

```js
var $clone = $('#allProducts').clone();
$clone.find("b, br").remove();

// console.log($clone.html());
// $clone.removeAttr('id').appendTo('body');
```

E você continua com a vantagem de poder manipular os elementos de `$clone` sem precisar parsear o conteúdo novamente.

```js
$clone.find('.button-produto').on('click', function () {});
$clone.find('.edit-input').on('input change', function () {});
(...)
```

E assim vai.